# If $y=\sin(m\arcsin x)$ then prove that $(1-x^2)y_{n+2}-(2n+1)xy_{n+1}+(m^2-n^2)y_n=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

If $y=\sin(m\arcsin x)$ then prove that $(1-x^2)y_{n+2}-(2n+1)xy_{n+1}+(m^2-n^2)y_n=0$, where $y_n$ is the $n$-th derivative of $y$, and hence obtain the Taylor series expansion for $\sin(m\arcsin x).$

I tried solving the problem as follows:

We can easily verify, that $(1-x^2)y_{n+2}-(2n+1)xy_{n+1}+(m^2-n^2)y_n=0$ holds true, when $n=0,$ where $y_0=y.$

Assuming $(1-x^2)y_{n+2}-(2n+1)xy_{n+1}+(m^2-n^2)y_n=0$ holds true, at $n=k$ i.e $(1-x^2)y_{k+2}-(2k+1)xy_{k+1}+(m^2-k^2)y_k=0\tag 1$

Differentiating the above equation $(1)$  with respect to $x$ we have, $(1-x^2)y_{k+3}-(2k+3)xy_{k+2}+(m^2-(k+1)^2)y_{k+1}=0,$ i.e $(1-x^2)y_{n+2}-(2n+1)xy_{n+1}+(m^2-n^2)y_n=0$ holds true for $n=k+1.$

So, by Principle of Mathematical Induction, we have, $(1-x^2)y_{n+2}-(2n+1)xy_{n+1}+(m^2-n^2)y_n=0,$ true $\forall n\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}.$

---

I could solve the rest part as it directly followed from that differential equation. But my question is, whether this is a valid way to prove, $(1-x^2)y_{n+2}-(2n+1)xy_{n+1}+(m^2-n^2)y_n=0$ as never before, I used the principle of mathematical induction to prove differential equations.

Comment: Yes, why not?  What;s true is true. Mathematical induction is valid in all areas of mathematics.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks a ton! I really needed this confirmation as to  whether my approach has any errors or not.

Comment: Are you sure you want subscripts for both differentiation (as in your $y_n,y_{n+1},y_{n+2}$) and for $y_m=\sin(m\arcsin x)$ which has nothing to do with differentiation?

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry for the typo! Thanks for pointing it out. I've fixed it.

Comment: @Thomas Finley, you've made it worse, now $(y_n)$ is a constant sequence of functions. Judging from your proof, you probably want $y_n$ to be $n$-th derivative , i.e. $y_n(x) = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\sin(m\arcsin x)$.

Comment: @Ennar I am so sorry. Fixed it.